# How to get the value from SPOP safely and test for value or null

Tags: lua, redis

I am currently doing 2 steps in my code and I just realized I can combine both steps in a LUA script.

I am doing:

1. SPOP on my set
2. calling a lua script to do other things.

The value from step#1 is being passed and stored in the local variable `ele`.

My lua script looks like:

```
local ele = KEYS[1]
local p = KEYS[2]
local u = KEYS[3]
if redis.call("SISMEMBER", u, ele) == 0 then
   ..
   ..
   return "OK"
else
  return "EXISTS"
end
```

How can I call SPOP from inside my lua script and store it in a variable.

I need to do:

```
local popped = redis.call("SPOP", "my-set-here")
```

I'm not sure if that will work, but then I have to check if it is null or has a value I guess.  Just want to make sure I am following best practise.

BTW, as a side note, what is the fastest way to create and test lua scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of `popped` for non-nillness with something like:

```
if popped then
  -- do something
end
```

As for developing Redis Lua scripts, have a look at Zerobrane's integration:

- http://notebook.kulchenko.com/zerobrane/redis-lua-debugging-with-zerobrane-studio
- https://redislabs.com/blog/zerobrane-studio-plugin-for-redis-lua-scripts/

Disclosure: I was involved in the integration effort ;)